# What does "Failed to parse video codecs correctly." mean?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express, webrtc, agora.io

I deploy this Agora.io Webrtc sample on launching Express + node.js webserver on chrome browser in accordance with [WebRTC documents](https://docs.agora.io/en/user_guide/communication/webrtc_user_guide_communication.html).

```
This appears to be Chrome
(index):78 Init AgoraRTC client with vendor key: ***
AgoraRTCSDK-1.8.0.js:842 INFO: Client in Live mode
(index):83 AgoraRTC client initialized
AgoraRTCSDK-1.8.0.js:842 INFO: VOSGateway connected.
(index):85 User 2502359564 join channel successfully
AgoraRTCSDK-1.8.0.js:842 DEBUG: Requested access to local media
AgoraRTCSDK-1.8.0.js:842 DEBUG: Object {video: Object, audio: true, fake: undefined}
adapter.js:32 chrome: {"video":{"mandatory":{"minWidth":1280,"minHeight":720,"maxWidth":1280,"maxHeight":720,"maxFrameRate":25,"minFrameRate":25},"optional":[]},"audio":true}
AgoraRTCSDK-1.8.0.js:842 INFO: User has granted access to local media.
(index):94 getUserMedia successfully
AgoraRTCSDK-1.8.0.js:842 DEBUG: Safari
AgoraRTCSDK-1.8.0.js:842 DEBUG: Set Video Bitrate - min:30 max:1500
adapter.js:340 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to parse SessionDescription.  Failed to parse video codecs correctly.
(anonymous) @ adapter.js:340
(anonymous) @ adapter.js:332
webkitRTCPeerConnection.(anonymous function) @ adapter.js:331
(anonymous) @ AgoraRTCSDK-1.8.0.js:457
AgoraRTCSDK-1.8.0.js:842 INFO: video dimensions: 1280 720
```

I got failed result and tried to re-install some google chrome versions contained v54, v56, v57, v59 and latest one. But every chrome version have same error that

`adapter.js:340 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to parse SessionDescription.  Failed to parse video codecs correctly.`

What does mean it?

Answer (score 1):

The "Failed to parse video codecs correctly" error is a known sdp compatibility issue caused by setMaxBW interface. The 1.8.0 version isn't recommended as it is outdated. I'd recommend upgrade to the latest version.